# WcfService in x64 using ODP.NET x64 fails (.NET 4.5 and 4.0)

Tags: 64-bit, windows-8.1, odp.net, iis-8

I have Windows 8.1 64 bit, VS 2012 32 bit , IIS 8.5, IIS Express 32 bit.

WcfService project Target Framework: .NET 4.5 - ImageRuntimeVersion: v4.0.30319

Service .NET 4.5 hosted in IIS 8.5 -> References Oracle.DataAccess.dll  ProcessorArchitecture: Amd64 Version: 4.121.1.0

ERROR executing OracleConnection.Open

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException     at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
```

Error for WcfService project with AnyCpu and WcfService project with x64
I test too using DllPath in section oracle.dataaccess.client and I get the same error

The same service NET 4.5 hosted now in IISExpress (x86)  -> References Oracle.DataAccess.dll  ProcessorArchitecture: X86 Version: 4.121.1.0
OK executing OracleConnection.Open

Any suggestions, how can I debug it or get logs about ODP.NET, and get solution ? is it possible?

I test again using Target Framework: .NET 4.0, and I get the same error (CLR 4.0 - v4.0.30319 the same for .NET 4.0 and 4.5)

I test too using DllPath, but wrong.

```
  <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>

      <!-- For X64 -->
      <!--<add name="DllPath" value="C:\app\Company\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin"  />-->

      <!-- For X86 -->
      <!--<add name="DllPath" value="C:\app\Company\product\12.1.0\client_2\bin"  />-->

    </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

Full logs

```
Test Name: Obtener_datos_de_OdpNet_con_servicio_AnyCPU_hosted_en_IIS

ERROR select sysdate from dual


Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException     at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()




*** LOG ***


Environment Data:
ProcessName: w3wp
Is64BitOperatingSystem: True
Is64BitProcess: True
SystemConfigurationFile: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config
ConfigurationFile: C:\TFS\Main\MyCompany.Lite.Frk\Net4.0\Tests\Apps\WcfService\web.config
MainModule.FileName: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
MainModule.ModuleName: w3wp.exe
BaseDirectory: C:\TFS\Main\MyCompany.Lite.Frk\Net4.0\Tests\Apps\WcfService\
ApplicationBase: C:\TFS\Main\MyCompany.Lite.Frk\Net4.0\Tests\Apps\WcfService\
FriendlyName: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-2-130404614116233936
ApplicationName: c36153ea

Assembly Data:
Location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2090c609\c36153ea\assembly\dl3\92d3ec19\79a8efa4_4d4acf01\MyCompany.Lite.Frk.Data.Tests.WcfServiceLibrary.dll
ProcessorArchitecture: MSIL
Referenced Assemblies of MyCompany.Lite.Frk.Data.Tests.WcfServiceLibrary
          mscorlib - None      Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll - Amd64
          System - None        Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll - MSIL
          System.Core - None        Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll - MSIL
          Oracle.DataAccess - None       Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.112.2.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll - Amd64
          System.Data - None        Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll - Amd64
          System.ServiceModel - None     Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll - MSIL
          MyCompany.Lite.Data - None         Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2090c609\c36153ea\assembly\dl3\08991152\90904b1f_c349cf01\MyCompany.Lite.Data.dll - MSIL
          Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data - None        Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2090c609\c36153ea\assembly\dl3\261813e9\c453c0e2_d648cf01\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll - MSIL
          System.Runtime.Serialization - None       Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll - MSIL

Oracle.DataAccess Data:
Assembly: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
AssemblyQualifiedName: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
Module.FullyQualifiedName: C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.121.1.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
Location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.121.1.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
ProcessorArchitecture: Amd64
Version: 4.121.1.0
FullName: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
GlobalAssemblyCache: True


PortableExecutableKinds: ILOnly, PE32Plus
ImageFileMachine: AMD64


Creating connnection using Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection to MyCompany.ConnectionStrings.Oracle.MYSCHEMA
Connnection False
TestOdpNetConnection using Oracle.DataAccess. Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=SERVERDB)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=oas1d)));User Id=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;
Oracle.DataAccess. Abriendo conexión a Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=SERVERDB)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=oas1d)));User Id=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;
TestOdpNetConnection. Error en la conexión.


Msg: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException     at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at MyCompany.SourceRepository.OdpNetHelper.TestOdpNetConnection(String connectionString, String& trace) in c:\TFS\Main\MyCompany.Lite.Frk\Net4.0\Tests\Apps\WcfServiceLibrary\Common\OdpNetHelper.cs:line 60


Creating connnection using OdpNetDataContext to MyCompany.ConnectionStrings.Oracle.MYSCHEMA
ConnectionString: DATA SOURCE=MyDataSource;PASSWORD=XXXX;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=MYSCHEMA
Database: data source=MyDataSource;persist security info=true;
DbProviderFactory: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory


Executing ExecuteNonQuery


Test Name: Obtener_datos_de_OdpNet_con_servicio_AnyCPU
Test Outcome:   Passed
Result StandardOutput:   
TestContext Messages:
Result:
OK

*** LOG ***
Environment Data:
ProcessName: iisexpress
Is64BitOperatingSystem: True
Is64BitProcess: False
SystemConfigurationFile: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config
ConfigurationFile: C:\TFS\Main\MyCompany.Lite.Frk\Net4.0\Tests\Apps\WcfService\web.config
MainModule.FileName: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
MainModule.ModuleName: iisexpress.exe
BaseDirectory: C:\TFS\Main\MyCompany.Lite.Frk\Net4.0\Tests\Apps\WcfService\
ApplicationBase: C:\TFS\Main\MyCompany.Lite.Frk\Net4.0\Tests\Apps\WcfService\
FriendlyName: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-5-130404614413883655
ApplicationName: 6e9d8358


Assembly Data:
Location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9aada5e4\6e9d8358\assembly\dl3\12388fd2\79a8efa4_4d4acf01\MyCompany.Lite.Frk.Data.Tests.WcfServiceLibrary.dll
ProcessorArchitecture: MSIL
Referenced Assemblies of MyCompany.Lite.Frk.Data.Tests.WcfServiceLibrary
          mscorlib - None      Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll - X86
          System - None        Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll - MSIL
          System.Core - None        Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll - MSIL
          Oracle.DataAccess - None       Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.112.2.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll - X86
          System.Data - None        Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll - X86
          System.ServiceModel - None     Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll - MSIL
          MyCompany.Lite.Data - None         Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9aada5e4\6e9d8358\assembly\dl3\7ec82898\90904b1f_c349cf01\MyCompany.Lite.Data.dll - MSIL
          Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data - None        Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9aada5e4\6e9d8358\assembly\dl3\f06f5054\c453c0e2_d648cf01\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll - MSIL
          System.Runtime.Serialization - None       Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll - MSIL


Oracle.DataAccess Data:
Assembly: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
AssemblyQualifiedName: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
Module.FullyQualifiedName: C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.121.1.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
Location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.121.1.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
ProcessorArchitecture: X86
Version: 4.121.1.0
FullName: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
GlobalAssemblyCache: True

PortableExecutableKinds: ILOnly, Required32Bit
ImageFileMachine: I386


Creating connnection using Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection to MyCompany.ConnectionStrings.Oracle.MYSCHEMA
Connnection True
TestOdpNetConnection using Oracle.DataAccess. Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=SERVERDB)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=oas1d)));User Id=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;
Oracle.DataAccess. Abriendo conexión a Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=SERVERDB)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=oas1d)));User Id=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;
Oracle.DataAccess.OracleConnection State:  Open
Oracle.DataAccess.OracleConnection ServerVersion:  11.2.0.3.0
Oracle.DataAccess.OracleConnection DataSource:  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=SERVERDB)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=oas1d)))
Oracle.DataAccess.OracleConnection ServiceName:  sys$users
Oracle.DataAccess.OracleConnection InstanceName:  oas1d
Oracle.DataAccess.OracleConnection HostName:  SERVERDB
Oracle.DataAccess.OracleConnection DatabaseName:  oas1d
Oracle.DataAccess.OracleConnection DatabaseDomainName:  null
Conectado True y cerrando conexión


Creating connnection using OdpNetDataContext to MyCompany.ConnectionStrings.Oracle.MYSCHEMA
ConnectionString: DATA SOURCE=MyDataSource;PASSWORD=xxxxxx;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=MYSCHEMA
Database: data source=MyDataSource;persist security info=true;
DbProviderFactory: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory


Executing ExecuteNonQuery
Result: -1 para select sysdate from dual
```

My environment:

I use Windows 8.1 64 bits.
I use VS 2012 Ultimate 32bit
I have installed:

```
64-bit ODAC 11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1) Xcopy for Windows x64
Location: C:\app\Company\odp.net\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll - ProcessorArchitecture: Amd64
Location: C:\app\Company\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll - ProcessorArchitecture: Amd64

ODAC 11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1)
Location: C:\app\Company\product\11.2.0\client_2\odp.net\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll - ProcessorArchitecture: X86
Location: C:\app\Company\product\11.2.0\client_2\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll - ProcessorArchitecture: X86

64-bit ODAC 12c Release 2 (12.1.0.1.2) for Windows x64
Location: C:\app\Company\product\12.1.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll - ProcessorArchitecture: Amd64
Location: C:\app\Company\product\12.1.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll  - ProcessorArchitecture: Amd64

ODAC 12c Release 2 (12.1.0.1.2) and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio
Location: C:\app\Company\product\12.1.0\client_2\odp.net\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll - ProcessorArchitecture: X86
Location: C:\app\Company\product\12.1.0\client_2\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll - ProcessorArchitecture: X86
```

TNSNames.ora in this paths:

```
C:\app\Company\Network\Admin
C:\app\Company\product\11.2.0\client_2\Network\Admin

C:\app\Company\product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin
C:\app\Company\product\12.1.0\client_2\Network\Admin
```

In GAC, I have all these references:

```
Oracle.DataAccess 32bit - 2.112.2.0 - CLR 2.0
Oracle.DataAccess 32bit - 2.121.1.0 - CLR 2.0

Oracle.DataAccess 64bit - 2.112.2.0 - CLR 2.0
Oracle.DataAccess 64bit - 2.121.1.0 - CLR 2.0

Oracle.DataAccess 32bit - 4.112.2.0 - CLR 4.0
Oracle.DataAccess 32bit - 4.121.1.0 - CLR 4.0

Oracle.DataAccess 64bit - 4.112.2.0 - CLR 4.0
Oracle.DataAccess 64bit - 4.121.1.0 - CLR 4.0

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess    MSIL  - 4.212.1.0 - CLR 4.0
Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC 32bit - 4.212.1.0 - CLR 4.0
Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC 64bit - 4.212.1.0 - CLR 4.0
```

Added:

For Tests.WcfServiceLibrary.csproj I add reference to Oracle.DataAccess x86.

Tests.WcfServiceLibrary.csproj is shared, it used for IIS sites x64  and for IISExpress sites x86.

Anyways, in executime time, it’s x64 loaded from GAC. View log:

```
*** LOG ***
ProcessName: w3wp
Is64BitOperatingSystem: True
Is64BitProcess: True

Assembly Data:
Location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2090c609\c36153ea\assembly\dl3\92d3ec19\fd0dc189_ea4ccf01\Tests.WcfServiceLibrary.dll
ProcessorArchitecture: MSIL
TargetFramework: .NET Framework 4.5
FullName: Tests.WcfServiceLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Referenced Assemblies of Tests.WcfServiceLibrary
                               Oracle.DataAccess - None                          Location C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.112.2.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll - Amd64
```

I get this in the code:

```
var t = typeof(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection);
var assembly = t.Assembly;
var asmName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assembly.Location);
```

and the log for Oracle.DataAccess Data:

```
Assembly: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
AssemblyQualifiedName: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
Module.FullyQualifiedName: C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.121.1.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
Location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.121.1.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
ProcessorArchitecture: Amd64
Version: 4.121.1.0
FullName: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
GlobalAssemblyCache: True
```

**OracleException.get_Number** gives me error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.get_Number()
   at SourceRepository.OdpNetHelper.TestOdpNetConnection(String connectionString, String& trace) in c:\TFS\0.SourceRepository\OdpNet\OdpNetHelper.cs:line 108
```

Anyways, I  get the error:

```
Msg: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException     at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at SourceRepository.OdpNetHelper.TestOdpNetConnection(String connectionString, String& trace) in c:\TFS\0.SourceRepository\OdpNet\OdpNetHelper.cs:line 61
```

OracleException.

```
Message: 
Error Code: -2147467259
HResult: -2147467259
Errors: 0
```

But no error code

Comment: Windows 8.1 isn't supported with 12.1 ODP.NET yet. You will need to drop back to 8.0 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/tech-info/sod-oracle-db-win81-win2012r2-2088197.pdf From the logs it looks like your app is picking up ODP.NET 11.2 anyway. If you want to try to hack this into working, I'd uninstall ODP.NET 11.2 at least because your app is picking it up for some reason and that has much less of a chance of working than 12.1 does.

Comment: @ChristianShay Works for x86, isn't for x64, using Oracle.DataAccess in GAC (version 4.121.1.0)